# Get Current running page in WPF navigation NavigationWindow

Tags: .net, wpf, navigation, navigationwindow

I m new in WPF, 
i am developing a navigation application of WPF,

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="KioskTraffic.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" Source="Home.xaml"
    WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowsNavigationUI="False" WindowStyle="None" Cursor="Arrow" Closing="NavigationWindow_Closing"></NavigationWindow>
```

and i have some page which display in this navigarionwindow like

```
<Page x:Class="KioskTraffic.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Height="768" Width="1024"
      Title="Page1">
```

How can i know which page is running currently under NavigationWindow.xaml.cs file?

I have a timer in this navigation window that want to check if current page is home.xaml then i don't want to start that timer.

Comment: Question needs more context and active participation by owner.

Comment: I Have edit my question in simple way and still waiting for answer....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get current running page in code behind using CurrentSource property of navigation window. As per your requirements, it's done using NavigationService.Navigate() method like below :

NavWindow.xaml :

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="WPFTest.MyNavWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" Source="ShopList.xaml" Grid.Row="1" 
        WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowsNavigationUI="True" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" Cursor="Arrow" Navigated="NavigationWindow_Navigated">
</NavigationWindow>
```

NavWindow.xaml.cs :

```
namespace WPFTest
{
    public partial class MyNavWindow : NavigationWindow
    {
        public MyNavWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NavigationWindow_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((NavigationWindow)this).CurrentSource.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

ShopList.xaml :

```
<Page x:Class="WPFTest.ShopList"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="ShopList">
<Grid>
    <Label Height="28" Margin="81,12,99,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">Shop List</Label>
    <Button Name="btnNext" Content="Go to Product list" Width="150" Height="30" Margin="0,50,0,0" Click="btnNext_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

ShopList.xaml.cs :

```
namespace WPFTest
{
    public partial class ShopList : Page
    {
        public ShopList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri("ProductList.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

ProductList.xaml :

```
<Page x:Class="WPFTest.ProductList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ProductList">
    <Grid>
        <Label Height="28" Margin="81,12,99,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">Product List</Label>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

It's working fine for me. Hope this solve your problem. Please feel free to ask if it not solve.

**UPDATE :**

If you want to navigate page using class name instead of Uri then you can get current source like :

```
MessageBox.Show(((NavigationWindow)this).NavigationService.Content.GetType().Name.ToString() + ".xaml");
```

Comment: I m getting error "Object Reference is not set an object of an instance" first time when my first page load, its ok but when i click to  button "this.NavigationService.Navigate(new TimeoutDisplay());" it gives me that error. From any page i want to get page name.

Comment: @ViralSarvaiya : there should be System.Uri("yourpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative) instead of TimeoutDisplay() in your code.

Comment: Here i m taking a class instead of URI.

Comment: Yes, that error comes from line : MessageBox.Show(((NavigationWindow)this).CurrentSource.ToString()); If you use class name instead of Uri then you can it like my updated answer.

Comment: @ViralSarvaiya : Have you solved your problem or still continue ?

Comment: @ViralSarvaiya : Please award me bounty as you have accepted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Upendra's accepted answer above lead me in the right direction.  My problem was I was using different WPF Pages inside a FRAME.  I needed to determine what page was being displayed inside the frame.  Here's how I figured it out.

```
    Object CurrentPage;

    private void LSK_1L_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPage = MCDU_Page_Frame.Content.GetType();
    }
```

The CurrentPage object became the class name of the loaded page if used CurrentPage.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

I found out my current page by looking at the Content property of the NavigationService of my container window.

Answer (score 1):

if we want to known current page with full path which display inside frame then we can use that:

```
string currentpage = Myframe.CurrentSource.OriginalString.ToString().Replace("yoursolutionname;component/", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Page Load Event in Every Page to remove Back Entries and to show only Current Page

Inside Page Load Use NavigationService function RemoveBackEntry()

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

The `NavigationWindow` has a property called `CurrentSource` which is the URI of the last page navigated

Comment: but in WPF it gives me URI only first time not after that, i m doing this.navigationservice.navigate(new MyNewpage()); for navigate to another page.